# Unable to symbolicate crash reports

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I submitted a new version of my app to AppStore and it got rejected due to some crashes that I never experienced while testing the app.

Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to reproduce the issue so all I have to analyze the 2 unsymbolicated crash logs (.txt files) they sent me.
However, I am having problems symbolicating them.

[Crash Log 1](https://pastebin.com/8eis3Y0T)

[Crash Log 2](https://pastebin.com/eQu3nRrH)

I tried following the steps provided [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATE_WITH_ATOS) and [HERE](http://noverse.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-deal-with-an-iphone-crash-report/), as well as other suggestions but no luck.

Here are the things I tried so far:

```
$ atos -arch arm64 -o Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear -l 0x1839fa000 0x0000000183a1c2e8
```

Unfortunately the command returns only `0x00000001000222e8 (in Qlear)`

```
$ atos -arch arm64  -o 'Qlear.app'/'Qlear' 0x1839fa000
$ atos -arch arm64  -o 'Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear' 0x1839fa000
```

Both commands return `0x1839fa000`

```
$ dwarfdump --uuid Qlear.app.dSYM
$ dwarfdump --uuid Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear
```

Both commands return

```
UUID: 4FFCBD15-01BA-366A-8C28-E4E613401616 (armv7) Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear
UUID: 97BD48FC-11E3-37C9-A081-700DCE0CDB23 (arm64) Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear
```

If I try `$ dwarfdump --lookup 0x1839fa000 -arch arm64 Qlear.app.dSYM` I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: Qlear.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Qlear (arm64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking up address: 0x00000001839fa000 in .debug_info... not found.
Looking up address: 0x00000001839fa000 in .debug_frame... not found.
```

So in the end I thought the .dSYM files(I tried the one on my Mac as well as the one from iTunes Connect) are corrupted so I tried `dwarfdump --all Qlear.app.dSYM` but this seems to be working as it returns a lot of content.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Am I mixing up the commands, am I using the wrong hex?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours of searching I finally found a solution:

1. Change the crash logs extension from **.txt** to **.crash.**. This is very important since .txt files are not recognized. I was also unable to find any info on this while reading Apple documentation.
2. Connect an iOS device and start Xcode.
3. In Xcode, go to **Windows > Devices and Simulators** (Shift + CMD + 1)
4. Select the **Devices** tab and then **View Devices Logs**.
5. In the left pane, select **This Device** and then drag-n-drop the .crash files inside.
6. Wait for the files to load and get symbolicated. The logs can also be symbolicated manually after drag-n-drop: Right Click on the log > Re-Symbolicate Log.